# Why is Perl giving "Can't modify string in scalar output" error?

Tags: arrays, loops, perl, if-statement, hash

I'm pretty new to Perl and this is my most complex project yet. Apologies if any parts of my explanation don't make sense or I miss something out - I'll be happy to provide further clarification. It's only one line of code that's causing me an issue.

**The Aim:**

I have a text file that contains a single column of data. It reads like this:

```
0
a,a,b,a
b,b,b,a
1
a,b,b,a
b,b,b,a
```

It continues like this with a number in ascending order up to 15, and the following two lines after each number are a combination of four a's or b's separated by commas. I have tied this file to an array `@diplo` so I can specify specific lines of it.

I also have got a file that contains two columns of data with headers that I have converted into a hash of arrays (with each of the two columns being an array). The name of the hash is $lookup and the array names are the names of the headings. The actual arrays only start from the first value in each column that isn't a heading. This file looks like this:

```
haplo           frequency
"|5,a,b,a,a|"   0.202493719
"|2,b,b,b,a|"   0.161139191
"|3,b,b,b,a|"   0.132602458
```

This file contains all of the possible combinations of a or b at the four positions combined with all numbers 0-14 and their associated frequencies. In other words, it includes all possible combinations from "|0,a,a,a,a|" followed be "|1,a,a,a,a|" through to "|13,b,b,b,b|" and "|14,b,b,b,b|".

I want my Perl code to go through each of the combinations of letters in @diplo starting with a,a,b,a and record the frequency associated with the row of the haplo array containing each number from 0-14, e.g. first recording the frequency associated with "|0,a,a,b,a|" then "|1,a,a,b,a|" etc.

The output would hopefully look like this:

```
0   #this is the number in the @diplo file and they increase in order from 0 up to 15
0.011     0.0023    0.003    0.0532    0.163    0.3421    0.128    0.0972    0.0869    0.05514    0.0219    0.0172    0.00824    0.00886    0.00196 #these are the frequencies associated with x,a,a,b,a where x is any number from 0 to 14.
```

**My code:**
And here is the Perl code I created to hopefully sort this out (there is more to create the arrays and such which I can post if required, but I didn't want to post a load of code if it isn't necessary):

```
my $irow = 1;   #this is the row/element number in @diplo
my $lrow = 0;      #this is the row/element in $lookup{'haplo'}
my $copynumber = 0;
#print "$copynumber, $diplo[2]";
while ($irow < $diplolines - 1) {
  while ($copynumber < 15) {
    while ($lrow < $uplines - 1) {
      if ("|$copynumber,$diplo[$irow]|" = $lookup{'haplo'}[$lrow]) {  ##this is the only line that causes errors
        if ($copynumber == 0) {
          print "$diplo[$irow-1]\n"; 
          #print "$lookup{'frequency'}[$lrow]\t";
        }
        print "$lookup{'frequency'}[$lrow]\t"; 
      }
      $lrow = $lrow + 1;
    }
    $lrow = 0;
    $copynumber = $copynumber + 1;
  }
  $lrow = 0;
  $copynumber = 0;
  $irow = $irow + 1;
}
```

However, the line `if ("|$copynumber,$diplo[$irow]|" = $lookup{'haplo'}[$lrow])` is causing an error `Can't modify string in scalar assignment near "]) "`.
I have tried adding in speech marks, rounded brackets and apostrophes around various elements in this line but I still get some sort of variant on this error. I'm not sure how to get around this error.

Apologies for the long question, any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks for the suggestions regarding `eq`, it gets rid of the error and I now know a bit more about Perl than I did. However, even though I don't get an error now, if I put anything inside the `if` loop for this line, e.g. printing a number, it doesn't get executed. If I put the same command within the `while` loop but outside of the `if`, it does get executed. I have strict and warnings on. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the difference between `=` and `==`? (You probably want `eq` instead)

Comment: (And always `use warnings;` `use strict;` if you're not already doing so.

Comment: When I used =, it gave me an error saying it wouldn't work because I have set copynumber equal to a number. == seems to make it work. Is eq better?

Comment: Also I am using strict and warnings thanks, I just didn't include them here because the full script is a bit long

Comment: @NEW2R: I've added indentation (and some whitespace) to your code. Clear indentation is a powerful tool to help people understand your code and when you're asking a large number of strangers to read and understand your code, it's only polite to make that as easy as possible for them. You're welcome, of course, but please consider doing ot yourself next time.

Comment: Thanks @DaveCross, this wasn't something I was really aware of. I'll bear it in mind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problematic expression:

```
"|$copynumber,$diplo[$irow]|" = $lookup{'haplo'}[$lrow]
```

The equals sign (`=`) is an assignment operator. It assigns the value on its right-hand side to the variable on its left-hand side. Therefore, the left-hand operand needs to be a  variable, not a string as you have here.

I don't think you want to do an assignment here at all. I think you're trying to check for equality. So don't use an assignment operator, use a comparison operator.

Perl has two equality comparison operators. `==` does a numeric comparison to see if its operands are equal and `eq` does a string comparison. Why does Perl need two operators? Well Perl converts automatically between strings and numbers so it can't possibly know what kind of comparison you want to do. So you need to tell it.

What's the difference between the two types of comparison? Well, consider this code.

```
$x = '0';
$y = '0.0';
```

Are `$x` and `$y` equal? Well it depends on the kind of comparison you do. If you compare them as numbers then, yes, they are the same value (zero is the same thing whether it's an integer or a real number). But if you compare them as strings, they are different (they're not the same length for a start).

So we now know the following

```
$x == $y # this is true as it's a numeric comparison
$x eq $y # this is false as it's a string comparison
```

So let's go back to your code:

```
"|$copynumber,$diplo[$irow]|" = $lookup{'haplo'}[$lrow]
```

I guess you started with `==` here.

```
"|$copynumber,$diplo[$irow]|" == $lookup{'haplo'}[$lrow]
```

But that's not right as `|$copynumber,$diplo[$irow]|` is clearly as string, not a number. And Perl will give you a warning if you try to do a numeric comparison using a value that doesn't look like a number.

So you changed it to `=` and that doesn't work either as you've now changed it to an assignment.

What you really need is a string comparison:

```
"|$copynumber,$diplo[$irow]|" eq $lookup{'haplo'}[$lrow]
```

Comment: Thanks, this does get rid of the error and is nicely explained. However, even though I don't get an error, if I put anything inside the if loop for this line, e.g. printing a number, it doesn't get executed. If I put the same command within the while loop but outside of the if, it does get executed. I have strict and warnings on. Any ideas?

Comment: @NEW2R: If you think two values should be the same, but Perl claims they aren't, then the first thing to try would be to print out the two values just before you make the comparison. Something like `print "|$copynumber,$diplo[$irow]|" / <$lookup{'haplo'}[$lrow]>"`. Note I've put `< ... >` around the second value. This is a good tip as it allows you to see any whitespace characters that you might otherwise miss. My guess would be that one of the strings has a newline character at the end.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try and report back

Comment: Thanks, that really helped. It turned out the final issue was the speech marks, which I think were being misinterpreted, so I removed them from the file and combined with the eq, it works now

Comment: Re "*Are `$x` and `$y` equal?*", Or more relevant here, are `"abc"` and `"def"` equal? Yes (with two warnings) when using `==` (since non-numerical strings are treated as zero) and no for `eq`.

Answer (score 4):

`=` is assignment, `==` is numerical comparison, `eq` is string comparison.

You can't modify a string:

```
$ perl -e 'use strict; use warnings; my $foo="def"; 
           if ("abc$foo" = "abcdef") { print "match\n"; } '      
Found = in conditional, should be == at -e line 1.
Can't modify string in scalar assignment at -e line 1, near ""abcdef") "
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Nonnumerical strings act like zeroes in a numerical comparison:

```
$ perl -e 'use strict; use warnings; my $foo="def"; 
           if ("abc$foo" == 0) { print "match\n"; } '
Argument "abcdef" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at -e line 1.
match
```

A string comparison is probably what you want:

```
$ perl -e 'use strict; use warnings; my $foo="def"; 
           if ("abc$foo" eq "abcdef") { print "match\n"; } '
match
```